# Vue vuetify 3 slots not working properly with icons

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, icons, vuetify.js

When wrapping v-icon with slots, it renders a text instead of the Icon.

```
<v-icon>myprefix-plus</v-icon><!--works, renders an icon -->
<Icon>myprefix-plus</Icon> <!--renders a text -->
```

the result is as follows:
[image]

Icon component implementation is as simple as it can be:

```
<template>
  <v-icon><slot></slot></v-icon>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Icon",
});
</script>
```

Why it's not working with the slots and how can I make it working, to not change each occurrence of Icon component in project?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, to achieve it you have to use Vue [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html):  [`h()`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#h) and [`resolveComponent()`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#resolvecomponent)

Like the `IconSlot` does

```
const IconSlot = {
  setup(props, {slots}) {    
    const vIcon = resolveComponent('v-icon');
    return () => h(vIcon, null, slots.default());
  }
}
```

I would better do it then over `props`, like the `IconProp` does

```
const IconProp = {
  props: ['icon'],
  template: `<v-icon :icon="icon"></v-icon>`
}
```

and then

```
<icon-prop icon="mdi-vuetify"></icon-prop>
```

Here is the playground

```js
const { createApp, h, resolveComponent } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const Icon = {
  template: `<v-icon><slot></slot></v-icon>`
}

const IconProp = {
  props: ['icon'],
  template: `<v-icon :icon="icon"></v-icon>`
}

const IconSlot = {
  setup(props, {slots}) {    
    const vIcon = resolveComponent('v-icon');
    return () => h(vIcon, null, slots.default());
  }
}

const App = { components: { Icon, IconProp, IconSlot } }

const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app { line-height: 3; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  1. v-icon: <v-icon icon="mdi-vuetify"></v-icon><br/>
  2. icon: <Icon>myprefix-plus</Icon> <br/>
  3. icon-prop: <icon-prop icon="mdi-vuetify"></icon-prop><br/>
  4. icon-slot: <icon-slot>mdi-vuetify</icon-slot> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.4/dist/vuetify-labs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of the default slot by executing its render function:

```
import { useSlots } from 'vue'

const iconName = useSlots().default()[0].children
```

Have a look at [how Vuetify's VIcon does it](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VIcon/VIcon.tsx#L37-L44).